# My motorcycle bogs

Tags: honda, motorcycle, fuel-system, carburetor

I have a 2007 Honda shadow spirit 750. My motorcycle Boggs when I open the throttle, it idles fine. When I bought the bike the guy said the petcock was bad and that there are bigger jets installed in the bike. The guy also took the air intake off the bike and put a mesh over the carb. Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Try restricting the intake flow, like a stock air box and filter would do. The carburetors require restriction to work correctly.

Comment: Wasn't this asked yesterday, with the suggestion of replacing the petcock ?

Comment: Yeah it got flagged becuase of the way I worded things. I changed it so I could get more responses, thank you for the suggestions, I'll let you know tomorrow what happends when I restrict the airflow, is there any way I can test the petcock to see if it's actually working

Comment: Pull the fuel line off of it and see if it flows.